# How to exclude certain files from Gitlab changes which automatically trigger jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

As I'm new to CI/CD with Jenkins I couldn't able to identify a proper solution to avoid some changes in my readme other docs page which automatically triggers build in Jenkins.

With the help of the internet, I found two possible solutions: 
1) With `.gitlab-ci.yml` in project

This works fine and triggering only Git lab pipeline and I don't see it interacting with Jenkins. It would be helpful if you provide solution for it.

> Note:- I used gitlab free account -
>   https://gitlab.com/bnagarajan/citestproject and Jenkins in my local
>   environment.

2) With git plugin in Jenkins

I tried to use this plugin for this process and followed the steps given in the internet to resolve this and I couldn't able to achieve it. Build triggering for all changes.

[Jenkins_Git_plugin_exclude_region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EfJ0.png)

Someone please helps me to resolve the problem and help me to identify a permanent solution for it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add all those file types in the `.gitignore` file of your repository, Git uses it to determine which files and directories to ignore, before you make a commit. `. gitignore` file should be committed into your repository, in order to share the ignore rules with any other users that clone the repository you can get more info [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore)

Comment: Sorry am not talking about committing certain files i need avoid Git lab to push Jenkins build for committing changes to certain files

Answer (score -1):

You can exclude the files by creating the ".gitignore" file in git which will ignore the files like *.txt or A*.json files from workspace while triggering the build.

Comment: Sorry i tried the same its not working. I need to avoid Git lab to push Jenkins build for committing changes to certain files

Comment: GitLab always ignore files that are present in .gitignore file of that branch . Didn't got ,how its not working .